# Elasticbeanstalk; can't reach the page after trying to foward http to https

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My project that is deployed into elastic beanstalk doesn't work after updating it.

What I was trying to do is to configure https.

I was following [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/making-django-elastic-beanstalk-and-aws-rds-play-w)

and add `https.config` file.

```
files:

"/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":

    mode: "000644"

    owner: root

    group: root

    content: |

        RewriteEngine On

        <If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">

        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

        </If>
```

But after redeploying it, the site doesn't work. (It says can't reach this page.)

So I removed the file and redeployed it. But it seems like it's still looking for https:// page.

How can I fix this problem and how to forward HTTP to https correctly?

Comment: server needs a restart after changing files on server manually. Click on the environment, there click action>Restart App Server(s), try this and let me know what happens

Comment: It still doesn't work..

Comment: make sure your application is accepting connections on port 443. Go to environment>configuration>load balancer. Make sure there is a listener for port 443 too not only port 80. In my app's application load balancer I have listener for port 80 and 443, with protocol Http and Https respectively, and both are enabled. Https listener of course has SSL certificate for my domain too. If you are using classic load balancer settings will be similar, you will figure it out.

Comment: Actually I made dumb mistake.. I was trying to forward http to https with default domain name.